# sns barplot of all columns and rows of a dataframe from pd.describe()

Tags: python, dataframe, visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to compare the differences and similarities between 10 dataframes. I have decided to df.describe() each dataframe in turn and accumulate the results into a new dataframe.

```
    count     mean      std      min      25%      50%      75%      max
run                                                                     
0      38  11.9394  3.99795  2.66622  9.00963  13.6531  14.6516  18.2803
1      75  13.7902  2.69114  8.06895  13.5017  14.3492  15.4146  17.4614
2      17  13.9666  1.12535  11.1525  13.7025  14.1217  14.6637  15.6118
3      21  13.2841  2.81016  6.25177   13.198  14.0382  15.1457  16.2141
4      29  11.5376  3.35056  6.70377  8.43451  12.8287  14.7004   16.155
5      11  12.5245   3.0237  6.01391  11.0818  13.6772  14.6237   15.527
6      32  13.7039  2.36393  6.95464  13.6765  14.1967  14.8114  17.3966
7      11  13.9055  2.03886  10.5235  12.6321  13.9394  14.5784  18.0726
8      19  13.2579  1.80329  9.00478  13.0772  13.8909  14.1755  15.0772
9      28  13.2817  3.61778  5.64462  9.90116  14.6581  15.6785  18.7766
```

I thought from this point it would be trivial to do a barplot where each bar was a different variable (the columns) and they where hue'd according to which dataframe the variable was from(the rows).

However I can't work out how to split up the columns.

```
sns.barplot(data = describedWidth)
```

outputs the following graph

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XITl.png

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
df[df.columns].plot(kind = 'bar')
```

This, by default, should print all the columns with different legends. You can later customize according to your requirements I suppose.

You can also do this for your dataframe summary:

```
descDf = df.describe()
descDf[descDf.columns].plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Sample output:

[image]

---

PS: Apologies for the clumsy output image but you get the point I hope.

Comment: Thank you this is indeed the graph i wanted